# SpringBoot change scope for testing

Tags: spring, spring-boot

Is it possible to change the Scope of a Component without using @Scope when starting the testenvironment?

```
@Service
@Scope(${service.scope})
public class MyService{}
```

test.properties

```
service.scope=prototype
```

prod.properties

```
service.scope=
```

We don't want to polute the Service with a @Scope which we need only at testing.
Is there a better way to change the scope of a bean in a test? We don't have spring-cloud so we cannot use RefreshScope to refresh the scopes.

Comment: why would you need to change the scope for testing only? Have you tried `@DiritesContext` if your tests require a clean app context to run?

Comment: We want to execute multiple tests in parallel and change an injected path that the tests does not interfere with each other. If we have a singleton we will have race conditions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly I think my solution is the only "cool" one for this particular question to change the scope in the test environment.

Thankfully @DirtiesContext (Thanks to Darren :)) does the trick for my problem that I change the scope for every test.  The execution last a little bit longer in sequential mode but in parallel it works fine.

```
@Service
@DirtiesContext(classMode=ClassMode.AFTER_EACH_TEST_METHOD)
public class MyService{}
```